# read_table can not read the first line from .dat file correctly

Tags: python, dataframe

I use this code to read data from a `.dat` file using `read_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
rnames = ['user-id','movie-id','rating','timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\ml-1m\\ratings.dat', sep='::', header=None,names=rnames,encoding='utf8',engine='python')
```

The data from `.dat` file is as follows:

[image]

After reading from `dat`, it shows as follows:

[image]

Don't know why the first line will be read as NaN for `movie-id`, `rating` and `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your problem in Linux (Ubuntu), but it works fine:

```
import pandas as pd                                                          

rnames = ['user-id','movie-id','rating','timestamp']                         
ratings = pd.read_table('ratings.dat', sep='::',header=None,names=rnames,encoding='utf8',engine='python')

print ratings
```

My ratings.dat

```
1::1193::5::12345
1::661::3::123456
1::662::3::1234567
```

Output:

```
   user-id  movie-id  rating  timestamp
0        1      1193       5      12345
1        1       661       3     123456
2        1       662       3    1234567
```

So I guess it may be some problem in your Windows environment, other than the code you show above.

Comment: that's weird, can not find reason why i get such strange result,

Comment: change one computer then test, or check your data  with the first few lines maybe